# Cannot start emulator with Android 11

Tags: windows, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019, android-11

My environment is

- Windows 10 Home Single Language **21H1**
- VS2019 Community **16.11.7**
- Android Emulator **30.1.5**
- HAXM **7.5.6**

I can run **Android 9.0 (API 28)** in Android Emulator.

But I can't run **Android 10.0 (API 29)** and **Android 11.0 (API 30)** in Android Emulator. The emulator will start then stop by itself, no error message.

Following is my **Android 11.0 (API 30)**, others are set as default.

- Base Device: **Pixel 2 (+ Store)**
- Processor: **x86**
- OS: **R 11.0 - API 30**

I need to test in Android 11.0. What cause the error and how to fix it?

**Update 2021-12-01**

I've try following steps.

- Change from **fastboot.forceFastBoot** to **fastboot.forceColdBoot**. Not working.
- Reduce **hw.cpu.ncore** from **4** to **1**. Not working.
- Reduce **hw.ramSize** from **1536** to **768*. Not working.

I've try start the emulator from command, and here is what I got:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE" -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform -avd pixel_2_r_11_0_-_api_30 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_r_11_0_-_api_30
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start

Active code page: 65001
WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_r_11_0_-_api_30'), only 'qemu.*' properties are supported
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Active code page: 65001
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
VCPU shutdown request
emulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 255 ms
```

Thanks